# autohotkey how to cycle through array

Tags: autohotkey

I'm mainly a javascript developer and I'm starting to play with authotkey. I'm guessing if there is a better way to loop through an array than the way I'm using. Basically is like this:

```
cycle(value,maxValue){
 value += 1
 if value not between 1 and %maxValue%
    value :=1
 return value
}
```

Then I use it like this:

```
variable := cycle(variable,array.MaxIndex())
```

Seems a bit rudimentary. Is any other way?

**EDIT**:

I saw that my description was not clear. What I want is to get variables from the array in a circular way: when you ask for the next value and you are already at the last one, start again from the beginning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since what blackholyman did is correct, it is not aimed on arrays.
Here is an approach that now I know it works:

```
i:=0,somearr:= ["bla","morebla","bla bla"]
;-- do whatever stuff here
somearr[i:=i>1?--i:somearr.MaxIndex()]
```

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like what you need is a [for-loop](http://ahkscript.org/docs/commands/For.htm)

Example:

```
colors := Object("red", 0xFF0000, "blue", 0x0000FF, "green", 0x00FF00)
for key, value in colors
    s .= key "=" value "`n"
MsgBox % s
```

**Edit:**

As per your comment, this may be more towards your need

```
index := 0
maxValue := 10

f3::
tooltip % index := cycle(index, maxValue)
return

cycle(index, maxValue)
{
    return index := mod(index + 1, maxvalue)
}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Hello blackholman, now I see my question was not clear. I don't want to go through the whole array. I just want to get the next value on each key-press (for example) and then start again from the beginning once I reach the max value. In Javascript I would use the mod operator, but seems there is no easy way on AHK

Comment: Hello blackholyman. Yes, it is useful but I was looking for something more similar to my own answer. Thank you very much anyway.